# How to test a Vue mounted with an API call?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

I'm trying to test that some buttons have loaded from an API call when the page has loaded. The buttons exist on the page but when testing them with jest they don't exist. When I run some tests, all I get is an empty object.

**Welcome.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
      <h1> {{ title }} </h1>
      <button v-for="button in buttons" :key="button"> {{ button }} </button>
      <br>
      <button v-for="jsons in jsonData" :key="jsons"> {{ jsons }} </button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      title: 'Welcome page title',
      buttons: ['b1'],
      jsonData: {}
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.title = 'new title'
    this.buttons = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']

    axios.get('https://mocki.io/v1/cda5c244-485e-4f61-8035-ee7d8b8303bc')
      .then(response => (this.jsonData = [response.data[0].value, response.data[1].value, response.data[2].value]))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }
}
</script>
```

**welcome.spec.js**

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Welcome from '@/components/Welcome.vue'
import axios from 'axios'

jest.mock('axios');

describe("lifecycle methods", () => {
  let wrapper = null
  it("checks that the wrapper is updated",  async () => {
    wrapper = shallowMount(Welcome);

    expect(wrapper.vm.title).toBe('new title');
    
    expect(wrapper.vm.buttons).toContain('b3');

    expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith("https://mocki.io/v1/cda5c244-485e-4f61-8035-ee7d8b8303bc");

    await Vue.$nextTick()

    // have also tried this:
    // wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
    //   expect(wrapper.vm.jsonData).toBe('1')
    //   done()
    // })

    expect(wrapper.vm.jsonData).toContain('1')

  });
});
```

Comment: what does `all I get is an empty object` mean? Is your tests running or failing?

Comment: Expected value:  "1"
    Received object: {}
The test runs but this is what I get